# how to speed up display for continous images in android

Tags: android, android-imageview

Currently, I am trying an application for receive and display views from another mobile. When views received, I will convert it as a bitmap, and use ImageView to display them like 
imageView.setImagebitmap(xxx). However, I found the API performance is not good.

As I need display the continous images (not a video), is there any method to speed up the display?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using [SurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html) instead of `ImageView`. Every time you call `ImageView.setImageBitmap` new `BitmapDrawable` instance is created and view itself is invalidated so this is quite heavy way for switching images rapidly.

Also if you need to scale bitmap before drawing you can dramatically increase framerate by disabling [bitmap filtering](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setFilterBitmap%28boolean%29).